# table view displaying image which is in project

Tags: ios, tableview

i am trying to add image which i added in project i use following code for it

```
UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 320, 50)];
    [selectionView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"PlaceHolder.png"];
    UIImageView* blockView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    blockView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -5, 45, 45);

    if([[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"URL"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString:@"No Image"] ) 
    {


        [selectionView addSubview:blockView];


    }
    else
    {
        NSString *path = [[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"URL"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        AsyncImageView *imageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -5, 45, 45);
        imageView.imageURL=url;
        [selectionView addSubview:imageView];


    }
```

else condition work perfectly they have url of facebook to display images in table view but if condition in not working it going in to if condition but image is not getting displayed plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"];
UIImageView* blockView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

/*
imageNamed: is to load the picture which is in bundle. pass in the picture name
imageWithContentsOfFile: need to pass in the whole address of the file
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourfile.png"];
```

and add the image to the imageView and check the image file is aded to your project